# Exporting 3D data including color in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, printing, 3d-model

I am a beginner in using Qgis, and my goal is to print elevation models with color layers (e.g. rock or forest) with my 3D printer.
How do I get the 3D data exported from QGIS without losing the color information. .stl does not work. I would need to further edit the data in a CAD program (e.g. Solidworks or Oneshape).

Comment: What is your current process to get a .stl out of QGIS?

Comment: Hi. I use the "DEMto3D" AddOn.

Comment: I just found the AddOn Qgis2threejs. This exports the elevation data including color to a .gltf file. But the quality is bad and the .gltf is not possible to import to a CAD Software as i know. Other possibilities?